# Sound you make with your mouth

Tags: adjectives

The word that I can't remember was in a movie where one of the main characters made flower arrangements, and this guy who liked her saw them somewhere on a table in a hallway and tilted the picture that was hung on the wall behind the flowers, then he went to a book store and looked the word up in a dictionary and its definition was something like "the popping sounds your lips make when you pop your lips".

It was a really weird sounding word.

Answer (score 4):

Poppysmic. Found [here](http://www.livelaughrowe.com/quidnunc-and-poppysmic/). Loved that movie.

> poppysmic [pa'pee'smik]
>   n: the sound produced by smacking one’s lips

Another word from the movie [Love Happens](http://movies.msn.com/movies/movie-critic-reviews/love-happens.3/) is quidnunc.

> quidnunc [kwid'nuhngk]
>   n: a person who is eager to know the latest news and gossip; a gossip or busybody.

Comment: Actually, *poppysmic* is a nonsense word used by James Joyce in  Chapter 15, *(Circe)* of his 1920 work *Ulysses*, [(Florry whispers to her. Whispering lovewords murmur lip-lapping loudly, **poppysmic** plopslop.](http://www.online-literature.com/james_joyce/ulysses/15/) But who can say *exactly* what he meant by it?

Comment: Interesting, @FumbleFingers - I didn't know that.
Well, the reference in the movie means this. At least, if the asker and I are thinking the same movie.

Comment: @ LitheOhm: I didn't really register OP's *what's this "word" I heard in a movie?* when I posted an answer. If I had, I might have just closevoted as "belongs on [movies.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/)", because a "word" that's only been used twice in a century is hardly "English".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fair enough. I only got it because I remembered that movie and not through any mastery of the English language, too. I lack the rep to close-vote over here but you could do so if you'd like.

Comment: Nah - it's still relevant to ELU that apparently we don't actually *have* anything that could really be called an *English **word*** for what OP describes. Incidentally, *quidnunc* goes back to at least 1700, and has [26,500](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=quidnunc&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) citations in Google Books - it just happens to be mentioned in *Love Happens*. But there are only 83 instances of *poppysmic* in GB, and if I look at the handful earlier than 2009 (when *Love Happens* came out) they all seem to be quoting the Joyce usage.

Comment: ...I haven't watched *Love Happens*, but the word doesn't occur in a subtitle file I just checked. Nor does *smacking* or *lips*, so they're apparently not discussing the definition you quote. I assume you get to *see* the word written somewhere, but I don't see how it would thereby be "defined".

Answer (score 1):

There's [smack one's lips](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smack+ones+lips), but that's almost always used effectively "figuratively".

I can't find any dictionaries that agree with me, but personally I'd use [**gob**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gob). Apparently it's mainly a BrE usage. For me the primary meaning is *to spit* (or as the combination *gob off = boast, complain,* or otherwise use your mouth pointlessly/irritatingly).

I also found an (old) written instance of [plopping his lips](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=X-QBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA90&dq=%22plopping%20his%20lips%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FJD5UYfsPOHH0QXw7YCACA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22plopping%20his%20lips%22&f=false), which I assume refers to the same thing.

Comment: Interesting! As an American the word *gob* simply means *mouth* to me, and I can only think of it being used as "shut your gob" (though I don't think it's anything like a common phrase). Your *gob off* seams to be akin to our *mouth off*, which has the same meaning.

Comment: @Wendi: Here's [Rat Scabies Sid walked onstage and some punter gobbed at him — so he smacked him with the mic stand.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22some+punter+gobbed+at+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) as an example of *gob=spit* (that'll be BrE). But [Papa gobbed it with relish 'n catsup, mmm . . .](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Papa+gobbed+it+with+relish%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is bound to be AmE (our *catsup* is *ketchup*). We all use *gob* creatively, not just as an exact replacement for *mouth*. You can't *gob words*, for example, but you can mouth them.